# Rails - Confirmation of numeric attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying Ruby on Rails for a few months now, re-engineering a desktop application. This application has a form for updating take-off and landing points, whose coordinates must be confirmed. Well, I tried validates_confirmation_of method however it works only with String attributes, and I have Integer and Decimal types. Hence I created an alternative method by borrowing an excerpt from the helper (confirmation.rb), which is working fine. But I wonder if there is another way to do it or whether this solution can be improved. Below follows a compact version of the source files. Thanks in advance!

Migration:

```
class CreateWaypoints < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :waypoints do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :latitude_in_degrees
      t.integer :latitude_in_minutes
      t.decimal :latitude_in_seconds, precision: 5, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :waypoints, [:name], unique: true
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@waypoint) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inline">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <%= f.input :latitude_in_degrees %>
    <%= f.input :latitude_in_minutes %>
    <%= f.input :latitude_in_seconds %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <%= f.input :latitude_in_degrees_confirmation, as: :numeric, label: false %>
    <%= f.input :latitude_in_minutes_confirmation, as: :numeric, label: false %>
    <%= f.input :latitude_in_seconds_confirmation, as: :numeric, label: false %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Model:

```
class Waypoint < ApplicationRecord
...

  validates_each :latitude_in_degrees, :latitude_in_minutes, :latitude_in_seconds do |record, attribute, value|
    if record.send("#{attribute}_changed?")
      confirmed = record.send("#{attribute}_confirmation")
      if confirmed.to_s != value.to_s
        human_attribute_name = record.class.human_attribute_name(attribute)
        record.errors.add(:"#{attribute}_confirmation", "Doesn't match #{human_attribute_name}")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: If they must match exactly you can just cast to a string or use the raw value for comparison instead of rounding

Comment: Ok, casting to String is a good solution, and so i was able to delete a line from the original method. But how would you compare the raw values, as the input (confirmed) may be a nil or a string and 'value' a Integer or Decimal? Thanks!

Comment: Use the bracket accessors self[:latitude_in_degrees]

Comment: I can't figure out what the benefit of doing that in this block...can you give me a hint, please?